# How to set the value of the form field from another one?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-inputfilter

For example we have a form with two fields, filters and validators:

```
$factory = new \Zend\Form\Factory();
$form = $factory->createForm([
    'elements' => [
        [
            'spec' => [
                'name' => 'fieldOne',
                'type'  => 'Text',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'spec' => [
                'name' => 'fieldTwo',
                'type' => 'Text',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'input_filter' => [
        'fieldOne' => [
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
            ],
            'validators' => [                      
                new \Application\Validator\FieldOneValidator(),
            ],
        ],
        'fieldTwo' => [
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StringToUpper'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

If `fieldOne` is valid and `fieldTwo` is empty, then we need to set the filtered value form `fieldOne` into `fieldTwo` and filter it.

```
$form->setData([
    'fieldOne' => '    test    ',
    'fieldTwo' => '',
]);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->getData(); // ['fieldOne' => 'test', 'fieldTwo' => 'TEST']
}

$form->setData([
    'fieldOne' => '    test    ',
    'fieldTwo' => 'not empty',
]);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->getData(); // ['fieldOne' => 'test', 'fieldTwo' => 'NOT EMPTY']
}
```

How to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'identical' validator:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Identical.php#L154

In your validator, there's a second parameter `$context` passed to isValid which gives you the values in the form.

There you want to leverage how other fields are filled, to validate your current field.

*In other words create a custom validator, and use 'context' within your validator, which you attach to your field with dependencies.*

Comment: Validator is only validate the value, but I need to change it using the context.